# How to add the current query string value in my page's hyperlinks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, query-string

My code goal is to search various websites at once.

I would like to do this while generating a query string with the search terms.(Mainly for analytics reasons). I use a `form` to do so.

With java-script I add the search term `name` to the array of links `linkList`.

Written from bits of code I found online, worked "fine" before adding the `form` part to generate my query string. Now it doesn't even display the links.

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">
</head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
      <script src="/scripts"></script>
<body>


    <form id="test-form">   
        <div>
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search"id="id"/>
      <button type="submit" id="go">get links</button> </div>   </form> 


      <div id="linkText"></div>
<div id="a">test</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //READ URL
    let params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
    let name = params.get("search");
    console.log(name) 
    //IF QUERY IN URL
    if(name !== null && name !== '') {
        // do something
     }
     else {
    //ARRAY LIST 1
    var linkList = {
            "https://google.net":"Click",
            "https://google.org=":"Click2",
            };

    //LINK GENERATION FROM ARRAY
    for (link in linkList) {
        if (linkList.hasOwnProperty(link)) {
          var a = document.createElement('a'),
              linkText = document.createTextNode(linkList[link]);
               //ADD THE QUERY AT THE END OF THE LINK
          a.href = link + name;
          a.appendChild(linkText);
          document.body.appendChild(a);
        }
      }
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an easier solution that solved my problem :

I search the URL for the query parameters and call them `name`

```
    let params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
    let name = params.get("search");
```

But I create the links in a less complicated manner

```
      document.write('<a href="' + foo + '" class = "bar">Link Name</a>');
      var foo = "http:example.com/search="+name;
```